# hive jdbc connect hbase

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am using Hadoop 2.7.3, HBase 1.2.3 and hive 2.1.0. hive query is ok, but hive jdbc query give java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

```
hduser@master:~> hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/hduser/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. tez, spark) or using Hive 1.X releases.
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: backward-delete-word
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: backward-delete-word
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: down-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: up-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: up-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: down-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: up-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: down-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: up-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: down-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: up-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: down-history
hive (default)> select * from hive_emp;
OK
1   anleapat    HD2 8000.0
2   anlea   HD2 123.0
Time taken: 3.053 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive (default)>
```

I start hiveserver using:

```
hive --service hiveserver2
```

listTable() and decribeTable() method running ok, but testQuery() method give 
outofmemomeryerror:

```
    public class HiveJdbcTest{

    private Statement stmt;

    private Connection conn;

    @Before
    public void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception
    {
        String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:hive2://master:10000/default";
        String user = "";
        String password = "";
        Class.forName(driverName);
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        this.stmt = conn.createStatement();

    }

    @Test
    public void listTable()
    {
        try
        {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("show tables");
            while (rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                conn.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void decribeTable()
    {
        try
        {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("describe hive_emp");
            while (rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                conn.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testQuery(){
        try
        {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from hive_emp");
            while (rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + "|" + rs.getString(2));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                conn.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.anlea.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.anlea.hadoop.parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.anlea.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

hive-site.xml:

```
<property>
      <name>hive.querylog.location</name>
      <value>/home/hduser/hive/logs</value>
    </property>

        <property>
          <name>hive.zookeeper.quorum</name>
          <value>sles11x64-1,sles11x64-2,sles11x64-3</value>
          <description>The list of zookeeper servers to talk to. This is only needed for read/write locks.</description>
        </property>
    <property>
    <name>hive.cli.print.current.db</name>
    <value>true</value>
    </property>
        <property>
  <name>hive.fetch.task.conversion</name>
  <value>more</value>
</property>
```

shell console:

```
    hduser@master:~> hive --service hiveserver2
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
    OK
    Exception in thread "AsyncLogger-1" 
    Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AsyncLogger-1"
    Exception in thread "HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-41" 
    Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-41"

eclipse console:

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/software/repo/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.4.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/software/repo/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.10/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readLength(TSaslTransport.java:376)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readFrame(TSaslTransport.java:453)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.read(TSaslTransport.java:435)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.read(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_FetchResults(TCLIService.java:559)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.FetchResults(TCLIService.java:546)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveConnection.java:1426)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.FetchResults(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet.next(HiveQueryResultSet.java:372)
    at test.HiveJdbcTest.testQuery(HiveJdbcTest.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
java.sql.SQLException: Error retrieving next row
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet.next(HiveQueryResultSet.java:396)
    at test.HiveJdbcTest.testQuery(HiveJdbcTest.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readLength(TSaslTransport.java:376)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readFrame(TSaslTransport.java:453)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.read(TSaslTransport.java:435)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.read(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_FetchResults(TCLIService.java:559)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.FetchResults(TCLIService.java:546)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveConnection.java:1426)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.FetchResults(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet.next(HiveQueryResultSet.java:372)
    ... 25 more
java.sql.SQLException: Error while cleaning up the server resources
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.close(HiveConnection.java:742)
    at test.HiveJdbcTest.testQuery(HiveJdbcTest.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readLength(TSaslTransport.java:376)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.readFrame(TSaslTransport.java:453)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.read(TSaslTransport.java:435)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.read(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_CloseSession(TCLIService.java:191)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.CloseSession(TCLIService.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveConnection.java:1426)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.CloseSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.close(HiveConnection.java:740)
    ... 25 more
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a Jira ticket i don't see any updates on this-https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9893

Comment: Try to tune heap size parameters for hiveserve container-- jdbc:hive2://master:10000/default?mapreduce.map.memory.mb=3809;mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx3428m;mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=2560;mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx2304m;